# Muting the audio not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, html5-audio

This happens to be my HTML, jQuery and CSS code. But clicking the image doesn't mutes the audio!

HTML Code

```
<audio autoplay loop preload="auto">
    <source src="assets/music/GoGoRhapsody.m4a" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<div id="sound"></div>
```

jQuery Code

```
jQuery('#sound').click(function(){
    if (jQuery(this).attr("class") == "muted") {
        jQuery(this).removeClass("muted");
        jQuery('audio').removeAttr("muted");
    }else{
        jQuery(this).addClass("muted");
        jQuery('audio').attr("muted", "muted");
    }
});
```

CSS Code

```
#sound{
    position: absolute;
    top: 2%;
    right: 2%;
    width: 2%;
    height: 3%;
    background-image: url(img/mute.png);
}
.muted{
    background-image: url(img/sound.png);
    width: 1%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**.prop()**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/), pass *true/false* to *mute/un-mute* it

```
jQuery('audio').prop("muted", true/false);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/sVwXH/328/)

Complete Code

```
jQuery('#sound').click(function(){
    if (jQuery(this).hasClass("muted")) {
        jQuery(this).removeClass("muted");
        jQuery('audio').prop("muted", false);
    }else{
        jQuery(this).addClass("muted");
        jQuery('audio').prop("muted", true);
    }
});
```

Additionally, You should use [**hasClass()**](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/), it determine whether any of the matched elements are assigned the given class.

Answer (score 2):

I did it once, on a website:

```
$(".sound").on('click', function(){
    if ($('#player audio').get(0).muted) {
        $('#player audio').get(0).muted = false;
    } else {
        $('#player audio').get(0).muted = true;
    }
});
```

Should work normally with you.